# Can you always write entropy as integral over space?

Tags: black-holes, entropy, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I am mostly interested in the entanglement entropy of the ‘‘outside region’’ (aka ‘‘$S_\text{out}$’’) in the holographic entanglement entropy formulation in [arXiv:1408.3203](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3203) and [arXiv:1307.2892](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2892). Take an (extremal) surface $X$ that lives on part of a an AdS-Cauchy slice $\Sigma$ of the spacetime. Can the entanglement entropy of the fields outside $X$ always be written in terms of an integral over $\Sigma$ or any other space region?

Comment: What does it mean when you say "outside" the extremal surface? As in the complement of $X$ on $\Sigma $ or are you also talking about the Cauchy-splitting nature in the sense of the entanglement wedge? And I did not get it when you ask "... always be written in terms of an integral over $\Sigma $ ...", I would appreciate maybe rephrasing or elaborating the question.